# Showing a text or another depending on the date

Tags: php, text, time

I would like to show a text depending on the summer/winter time. Meaning that I would like to have a code to tell that:

-if it is after 28 March then it returns "We are in summer time, here are our opening schedules:"

-and if is is before then it returns "We are in winter time, here are our opening schedules"

I found that code:

```
<?php
$date1 = new DateTime('20-08-2017');
$date2 = new DateTime('-3 months');
$date3 = new DateTime('-6 months');

if($date1 < $date2 && $date1 > $date3) {
echo "Inside Range"; }
else {echo "Out of Range";}
```

But I don't find it optimal because of the year that we need to enter.

Comment: I don’t see that code snippet you have shown take the 28th of March into account in any specific way in the first place here.

Comment: After 28 March till when?

Comment: @KevinGales Until the next hour change, so, it would be on 31st October.

Comment: Then from 28March till 31 October "summer" then after 31 till march 27 winter?

Comment: Basically, yes something like that, the text should be fancier, but that's the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on comments..you could use date function...
This script will echo summer from March 29 till October 31...then 1 November till march 28 will echo winter

```
<?php

$today = date("md"); 

echo $today;

if(($today > "0328") && ($today < "1101")){ //0328 means march 28

          echo "We are in summer time, here are our opening schedules:"; 
                                       } 
          else { echo "We are in winter time, here are our opening schedules:"; 

                                      }


?>
```

Comment: Thank you, that works well. You helped me a lot :)